# Is This Overkill to Retrieve an Int from a Web API REST call?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, json.net

This code works, but may be only as performant as a 112-year-old alcoholic:

```
try
{
    const string uri = "http://localhost:28642/api/departments/Count";
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Content from HttpWebRequest is {0}", s));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The Web API REST method being called simply returns an int. Is this StreamReader jazz overkill for getting that one simple value? If so, what is the preferred method?

Comment: Consider using WebClient.DownloadString for a rather simpler approach.

Comment: Manually writing access is overkill, IMOHO. (And no, using the stream isn't overkill: any relevant overhead comes from the request itself and the stream just provides access to the result.)

Comment: If it designed to return the count, I think that's okay; assuming, network bandwidth is cheap and latency is of no importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet is on the case - WebClient.DownloadString is easy as (eating) pie:

```
var client = new WebClient();
MessageBox.Show(client.DownloadString("http://localhost:28642/api/departments/Count"));
```

IOW, the code I originally showed is definitely overkill for retrieving a scalar value.

### UPDATE

Better yet:

```
private void buttonGetDeptCount2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(GetScalarVal("http://localhost:28642/api/departments/Count"));
}

private string GetScalarVal(string uri)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

Comment: Not so much though, if you'd a bunch of different webservice calls, some of which needed to be more involved, and then you needed to add one more that just got an int. In that case, being consistent with the other calls would be reasonable (and the possible basis for some refactoring to get some reuse going).

Comment: True, but there will probably be quite a few that retrieve scalar values, so this concise method is the cat's yowling.